# Do I need a vaccine for meningitis to go to Peru?

Tags: health, peru, vaccinations

I'm going to Peru, and maybe Bolivia and Chile, in April. I've been suggested to take a meningitis vaccine. Is it recommended? I come from Europe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the website from the [Travel Clinic (Dutch)](http://www.travelclinic.com/), ([Google Translated to English](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.travelclinic.com)), there is no vaccination needed for that. (As far as I know, only children get vaccinated for that). Check that website, it has a ton of information on the vaccination subject.

The vaccinations are not that great anyway (in the way that they protect you entirely). Meningitis can be caused by a virus or a bacteria (and a parasite or  fungus) and there are over a 100 bacteria/virus strains that can cause it, the vaccinations only protect for a small number of these.